# convergence is space of test functions and distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I have the following exercise.

Let $T: \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$
T: \varphi \to \langle T,\varphi \rangle = \sum_{m=1}^{+\infty} (\varphi(\dfrac{1}{m})-\varphi(0)- \dfrac{\varphi'(0)}{m})
$$
1. Prove that $T$ is an distribution.

2. Prove that $Supp(T)=\{0\} \cup \{\dfrac{1}{m}: m \in \mathbb{N}^{\star}\}$.
3. For $m \in \mathbb{N}^\star$ we consider a function $\varphi_m$ such as $\varphi_m=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$ neighborhood $[\dfrac{1}{m},1]$ and $0$ neighborhood $[0,\dfrac{1}{m+1}]$ such as $0 \leq \varphi_m \leq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$.
   Prove that there exists $\varphi$ such as $\varphi_m \to \varphi$ in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$.
4. Prove that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} T(\varphi_m)=+\infty$.
5. Deduce that there exists an distribution $T$ with compact support such as it now satisfies the relation 
   $$T(\varphi)= C \sup_{|\alpha|\leq k} \sup_{Supp(T)} |D^\alpha (\varphi)|$$

I have difficulties to reslves questions $3$ and $5$. Can you help me please mostly in question $3$.